# ReportViewer.Find not working

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have a textbox, and a link button. On the same page I have a reportviewer. 
The reportviewer is in updatepanel with linkbutton as async postback trigger.
I'm trying to find string (entered in textbox) in the report; when linkbutton is hit.

```
protected void lbtnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportViewer1.Find(txtSearch.Text.Trim(), 1);
}
```

But that line gives error: `Some parameters or credentials have not been specified` Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If `txtSearch` is a control you added, it will not be inside `ReportViewer1`. 
If `txtSearch` is a control inside your `ContentTemplate` you should be searching in that control as follows:

```
var txtSrch = (TextBox)myUpdatePanel.ContentTemplate.Controls.FindControl("txtSearch");
```

You can get the text value from there and then set the parameters for the ReportViewer1 and refresh it.

```
ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[1];
parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("Search", txtSrch.Text);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
ReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```